# Unable to run rake db:migrate or any other db related actions

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

Good afternoon,

We are trying to upgrade our application to Rails 5. The first step is to migrate from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 (yes we are a bit behind). However we are getting the following error when we try to run `rake db:migrate`

```
docker-compose run --rm web bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
[tunemygc] not enabled
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:85:in `capture'
(eval):2:in `table_exists_with_silencer?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:20:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:641:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:882:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `up'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in `migrate'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

We have done some investigation but can't find much in the way of other people having this issue. We are using postgres:latest docker image with pg 0.20.0 gem

Updated:

*Adding Gemfile for reference*

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.7'

# Fitmo gems
#gem 'fitmo-core', git: "https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/fitmo-core.git", require: 'fitmo'
#gem 'fitmo-core', git: "https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/fitmo-core.git", require: 'fitmo', branch: 'staging'
gem 'fitmo-core', git: "https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/fitmo-core.git", require: 'fitmo', branch: 'rails4'
#gem 'fitmo-core', path: '../fitmo-core', require: 'fitmo'

gem 'rails',                  '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'rack',                   '~> 1.5.2'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rack-cache'

# temp to be deleted after migration
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'


# Webserver
gem "puma"
gem "puma_worker_killer"

# Caching
gem 'memcachier',             '~> 0.0.2'
gem 'dalli',                  '2.7.0'
gem 'connection_pool'

# Monitoring
#gem 'newrelic_rpm'
#gem "skylight"
gem 'tunemygc'

# Database
gem 'pg',                     '~> 0.18.4'

# Rails plugins
gem 'i18n',                   '~> 0.6.11'                         #'~> 0.7.0'
gem 'lograge'

gem 'ice_cube',               '~> 0.13.3'

# User authentication
gem "devise",                 '3.5.1'                             #'~> 3.5.1'
gem 'oauth2',                 '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth',               '~> 1.4.2'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2',        '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-jawbone',       '~> 1.0'                            #'~> 1.0'

# User authentication
gem 'oa-openid',              '~> 0.3.2', :require => 'omniauth/openid'

# pub/sub integration
gem 'pusher'

# Layer integration
gem 'layer-identity_token'
#gem 'layer-ruby',             require: 'layer', github: 'benedikt/layer-ruby'
#gem 'layer-ruby',             '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'layer-ruby',             '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'rest-client',            '~> 1.8.0'

# Tools
gem 'oj',                     '= 2.9.9'                           #'~> 2.12.12'
#gem 'rabl'
#gem 'rabl',                   git: 'https://github.com/dhiemstra/rabl.git', branch: 'cache_prefix'
gem 'rabl',                   git: 'https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/rabl.git'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'chronic',                git: 'https://github.com/mojombo/chronic.git' #sorry mate

# Background jobs
gem 'resque',                 '~> 1.26.0'
gem 'resque_mailer',          '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'resque-scheduler',       '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'devise-async'#,           '~> 0.8.0'                          #'~> 0.10.1'

# Frontend
gem 'haml',                   '~> 4.0.3'                          #'~> 4.0.7'
gem 'haml-rails',             '~> 0.4'                            #'~> 0.9'
gem 'haml-contrib'
gem 'jquery-rails',           '~> 3.1.4'                             #'~> 4.0.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails',        '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'simple_form',            '= 3.2.0'                          #'~> 3.1.0'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem "rails-backbone",         '~> 1.2.0'    #'0.7.2'                             #'~> 1.2.0'

# Plugins
gem 'appsignal',              '~> 2.1.2'
gem 'geocoder',               '~> 1.1.5'                          #'~> 1.2.9'
gem 'timezone'
gem 'browser',                '~> 1.1.0'                          #'~> 2.2.0'
gem 'countries',              '~> 0.9.3'                          #'~> 0.11.5'
gem 'intercom-rails',         '~> 0.3.5'                            #'~> 0.2.28'

## Social and 3rd party vendors
gem "koala",                  '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'health_graph'#,           git: 'https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/health_graph.git'
gem 'jawbone',                git: 'https://github.com/andrewpbrett/jawbone-up-api'
gem 'fitbit-api-client',      require: 'fitbit'
#gem 'fitbit-api-client',      git: 'https://a7697bdc4b3d4d6a458bac5fba0f9af68a521eec:x-oauth-basic@github.com/fitmo/fitbit-api-ruby-client.git', require: 'fitbit'
#gem 'fitbit-api-client',      path: '../fitbit-api-ruby-client', require: 'fitbit'

gem 'mailchimp-api',          '~> 2.0.4', require: nil
gem 'analytics-ruby',         '~> 2.0.12', require: 'segment/analytics' # segment
gem 'mandrill-api',           '~> 1.0.51'                         #'~> 1.0.53'
gem 'stripe',                 '~> 1.15.0'                         #'~> 1.24.0'
gem 'opentok',                '~> 0.1.2', require: nil            #'~> 2.3.3'
gem 'activemerchant',         '~> 1.64.0'                         #'~> 1.52.0'
gem 'activeuuid'

gem 'net-ssh',                '!= 2.10.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

#removed :assets group as part of rails4 migration
gem 'sass-rails',           "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '~> 3.0.2.1'
gem 'coffee-rails',         "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'uglifier',             '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'coffee-script',        '2.2.0'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'haml_coffee_assets',   '~> 1.12.0'
gem 'execjs' # needed for haml_coffee_assets

group :development do
  gem 'derailed'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'silent-postgres'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem 'forgery'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails',     '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'memcache-client'
  gem 'database_cleaner'                                    # 1.5.0
  gem "rspec",                  "~> 3.5.0"
  gem "rspec-rails",            "~> 3.5.0"
  gem "rspec-mocks",            "~> 3.5.0"
  gem "email_spec",             "~> 1.6.0", :require => nil
  gem 'capybara',               "~> 2.5.0"
  gem 'nokogiri',               '~> 1.6.1'                    # 1.6.6.2
  gem "selenium-webdriver",     "~> 2.37.0"                   # 2.47.1
  gem "poltergeist",            "~> 1.6.0"
  gem 'spork',                  '~> 0.9.2'
  gem 'caulfield'                                             # 0.0.10
  gem 'launchy'                                               # 2.4.3
  gem 'vcr',                    '~> 2.6.0'                    # 2.9.3
  gem 'resque_spec',            '~> 0.17.0'
  gem 'simplecov',              require: nil                  # 0.10.0
  gem 'mock_redis'                                            # 0.15.3
  gem 'timecop',                '~> 0.8.0'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter',  '~> 0.2.3'
end
```

*fitmo-core gemspec file*

```
# encoding: utf-8

$:.unshift File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
require 'fitmo_core/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name         = "fitmo-core"
  s.version      = FitmoCore::VERSION
  s.authors      = ["Fitmo"]
  s.email        = "info@fitmo.com"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/fitmo/fitmo-core"
  s.summary      = "Fitmo models"

  #s.files        = Dir['{lib/**/*,spec/**/*,[A-Z]*}']
  #s.platform     = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  #s.require_path = 'lib'
  #s.rubyforge_project = '[none]'

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]

  s.add_dependency 'rake'
  s.add_dependency 'actionmailer',                        '~> 4.0.0'
  s.add_dependency 'activerecord',                        '~> 4.0.0'
  s.add_dependency 'activesupport',                       '~> 4.0.0'
  s.add_dependency 'railties',                            '~> 4.0.0'

  # temp to be deleted after migration
  s.add_dependency 'protected_attributes'
  s.add_dependency 'rails-observers'
  s.add_dependency 'actionpack-page_caching'
  s.add_dependency 'actionpack-action_caching'
  s.add_dependency 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'

  # Model plugins
  s.add_dependency 'paranoia',                            '~> 2.2.1'
  s.add_dependency 'acts-as-taggable-on',                 '~> 4.0.0'

  # File uploads
  s.add_dependency 'carrierwave',                         '~> 1.0.0'
  s.add_dependency 'rmagick',                             '~> 2.13.1'
  s.add_dependency 'fog'#,                                 '~> 1.28.0'
  s.add_dependency 'unf',                                 '~> 0.1.3'
  s.add_dependency 'mime-types'#,                          '~> 1.25'

  # Others
  s.add_dependency 'rpush',                               '~> 2.7.0'
  s.add_dependency 'net-http-persistent',                 '~> 2.9.4'
  s.add_dependency 'countries',                           '~> 0.9.3'
  s.add_dependency 'alchemist',                           '~> 0.1.7'
  s.add_dependency 'rest-client',                         '~> 1.8.0'
  s.add_dependency 'nokogiri'#,                            '~> 1.6.0'

  s.add_dependency 'ice_cube',                            '~> 0.13.3'
  s.add_dependency 'pg',                                  '~> 0.18.4'
  s.add_dependency 'activeuuid'

  s.add_dependency 'appsignal',                           '~> 2.1.2'

  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec',                   '~> 3.5.0'
  s.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner'
  s.add_development_dependency 'forgery'
  s.add_development_dependency 'factory_girl',            '~> 3.6.2'
  s.add_development_dependency 'vcr',                     '~> 2.3.0'
  s.add_development_dependency 'faraday',                 '~> 0.7.6'
  s.add_development_dependency 'timecop',                 '~> 0.7.3'
  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec_junit_formatter',   '~> 0.2.3'

  s.add_development_dependency 'micro_migrations'          #,        git: 'https://gist.github.com/2087829.git'

end
```

Any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: Is there a particular migration that is having this trouble or just migrating in general?

Comment: I'm assuming it is just the migration in general. I'm not seeing the usual output when it is runs each script and if there is a problem then stops at the migration with the error. Additionally, all the migration scripts worked on rails 3.

Comment: Show some migration code please

Comment: @Iceman you mean from the scripts? there are 662 files. Don't think you want me post all of them :) But as I said, these all worked fine before...and they have already been executed on the app so the db is up to date. This is why I don't think it is the scripts themselvles

Comment: No, please don't post 662 files. Did you update or upgrade anything before this started happening?

Comment: We have updated a number of gems as part of the migration from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 including the pg gem from 0.18.4 to 0.20.0

Comment: What I am noticing is that the bundle install is building with native extensions which it never did before. A number of the gems are now building this way. May be related to that?

Comment: The only thing I can find is this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4049

Comment: I took a look at that. Its 6 years old so don't think it is related. We are not using a silent-postgres gem nor is it a dependancy of the pg gem

Comment: Well, Rails 3.2 is also quite old which you're migrating from.

Comment: Sure, but it was working under Rails 3.2. Its not working under Rails 4

Comment: You can maybe show your Gemfile, maybe there are some gems that are causing this.

Comment: I've updated the description. I think I will also open an issue in the Rails project and reference that issue you referenced as the stack trace is similar and see if any one there can understand what is going on

Comment: Yes, I think that is the correct route, they must know the reason for this.

Comment: Appreciate your time

Comment: @Iceman just to let you know, the issue you were referencing was the cause of the problem. I hadn't realised we were using the postgres-silent gem. id10t error

Comment: Glad you found it out, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was due to the use of the postgres-silent gem which is deprecated